# Run a C program automatically when i open Firefox?

Tags: linux, firefox

I have written a C program, which will monitor all the communication taking place through the Firefox browser in Linux. So I need to execute my program as soon as Firefox starts. Please suggest me how do I do so.

Comment: Can't you just write a script that start them at the same time?

Comment: make an alias for launching firefox that first executes your program...

Comment: @nhahtdh I dont have much knowlegde about scripts. So please suggest me a script to do so

Comment: Why is C tagged? Can you see the answer to this question being any different if your program were written in C++ or C#? If so, would you either kindly add `C++` and `C#` tags or remove the `C` tag because IT DOESN'T BELONG!?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, by running your program when Firefox starts? Please put in some background information in your question - maybe there are other better way to do it that suits your situation.

Comment: @nhahtdh I m writing C program which will monitor all the communication taking place through the firefox browser in Linux.So i need to execute my program as soon as firefox starts

Answer (score 2):

Write a bash wrapper script

```
#!/bin/bash
my_c_program
firefox
```

Name it something useful and place it on a path that is mentioned in `$PATH`.

Alternatively, you can put it in an alias:

```
alias firefox_starter='my_c_program; firefox'
```

Put this line in your startup program (`.bashrc`)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a firefox extension which wraps your program in an [XPCOM Component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM). [Here is a tutorial for creating firefox extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension).